# Can't run any git command from my bitbucket pipeline script

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

Today, I am facing an issue with git commands on bitbucket pipelines.

When try getting the tags list, nothing happens (literally) and so, my $version variable is empty.

```
image: hashicorp/terraform

pipelines:
  custom:
    deploy-manually:
      - variables:  # List variable names under here
          - name: Environment
          - name: Action
      - step:
           name: Security Scan
           script:
             - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: Modify locals.tf file for $Environment
          trigger: manual
          script:
             - terraform init
             
             #Install dependancies
             - |
               echo "Install needed dependancies"    
             - apk update;
             - apk add jq;
             - apk add --no-cache curl ;
             - apk add bash;
             - apk add python3;
             - version=$(git tag --list | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$' | sort -V | tail -n1)
             - |
                echo "Latest tag found: $version"
              [...]
      - step:
          name: Deploy completed
          trigger: manual
          script:
            - terraform validate
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

In case of anybody face the same issue in the future, I fixed it.

This was caused by a "performance" limitation of bitbucket pipeline which only consider the last 50 commits.
So, il your tag (or anything else you are looking for) is older than 50 commits, it will not find anything.

To fix it, you'll have to add a commend to force your pipeline to clone the full repo on the step where you need it:

```
image: hashicorp/terraform

pipelines:
  custom:
    deploy-manually:
      - variables:  # List variable names under here
          - name: Environment
          - name: Action
      - step:
           name: Security Scan
           script:
             - pipe: atlassian/git-secrets-scan:0.5.1
      - step:
          name: Modify locals.tf file for $Environment
          clone:
            depth: full
          trigger: manual
          script:
             - terraform init
             
             #Install dependancies
             - |
               echo "Install needed dependancies"    
             - apk update;
             - apk add jq;
             - apk add --no-cache curl ;
             - apk add bash;
             - apk add python3;
             - version=$(git tag --list | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$' | sort -V | tail -n1)
             - |
                echo "Latest tag found: $version"
              [...]
      - step:
          name: Deploy completed
          trigger: manual
          script:
            - terraform validate
```